# Running ci on whatever is under the cursor in Vim

Tags: vim

Basically I want to hover over something like a bracket or quote, then when I press my key the command will automatically capture what is under my cursor and run **ci** on it.

So if I hover a **(**, it will run **ci(** etc.

I cant really figure out how to capture the current character under my cursor and pass it to the mapping. I found some commands to find the character under the cursor, but I wasnt able to use it in my remap.
Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can get the character under the cursor using:

```
let char_under_cursor=getline('.')[col('.')-1]
```

Next step, to check if the the char_under_cursor is one of `(,[, {,...`, your mapping will do `ci*`, you can consider using a `<expr> mapping`, here is an example:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F10> getline('.')[col('.')-1] == '('?'ci(' : '\<None>'
```

This example of mapping (F10) just checks if the char under the cursor is `(`, if yes, it does `ci(`, otherwise, it does nothing.

I think you get the idea how to check it, you can check if the char matches some regex to cover `],}...` cases. Also, you can write a little function including more complex logic and call the function in the `<expr>` mapping.

Good luck!

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. I cant help but wonder if there isnt a simpler solution though. Is there no way to simply append the getline command to a reguar ci. Something like this, nnoremap <expr> <F10> ci + getline('.')[col('.')-1]

Comment: @havardsj sure, you can do that. However, if it's a good idea, it depends on your requirement. for example, if your cursor is on a `W`, or `s` or `p` are you really want to remove the WORD, sentence, or paragraph? Only you can decide it. My example is just showing the direction.

Comment: I will only be using it to delete/change stuff within parentheses, bracket, quotes etc. I will keep looking into it, thanks again :)

Comment: @havardsj yes, you can consider what I wrote in the answer, define a list, or a regex pattern to check if the char in the desired range/list, and trigger the `ci*` or nothing/something else. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With help from Kent I managed to figure it out.

This command does everything I need for now.

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>f "ci".getline('.')[col('.')-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install and enable plug-in [wellle/targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim), then you can simply use the `ib` text object to select inside *any* block enclosed by the usual matching delimiters.

In your case, `cib` on top of the `(`, or really anywhere inside it (as long as that's not inside another block) would work to change the contents inside that specific block.

See ["Any Block"](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#any-block) in the README for that plug-in.

You also have a corresponding `iq` for quotes, which affects any of `"`, `'` or `` ` ``. The plug-in is also pretty smart about figuring out which quotes make up the string delimiters, even when you have multiple pairs or escaped quotes on a single line.

Comment: That is very interesting, I will definitely check it out. Thanks :D